# Updated OsX to El Captian Facing Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, osx-elcapitan

There when i update my system from OS X to El Capitan and then type 
"rails s" on terminal it shows like this "Could not find activesupport-4.2.5 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems." type of errors, when i run 'bundle install' it shows error like this

```
Installing commonjs 0.2.7
Installing concurrent-ruby 1.0.0
Installing geocoder 1.2.14
Installing geokit 1.10.0
Using bundler 1.12.1
Installing multi_json 1.11.2
Installing tilt 2.0.2
Installing libv8 3.16.14.13 with native extensions

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
current directory: /Users/paras/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.13/ext/libv8
/Users/paras/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20160505-78603-1apvxhs.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile
Compiling v8 for x64
Using python 2.7.10
Using compiler: /usr/bin/c++ (clang version 7.3.0)
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: file: /Users/paras/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.13/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/atomicops_internals_x86_gcc.o has no symbols
In file included from ../src/accessors.cc:28:
In file included from ../src/v8.h:60:
In file included from ../src/objects-inl.h:38:
In file included from ../src/elements.h:32:
../src/objects.h:5252:44: error: shifting a negative signed value is undefined [-Werror,-Wshift-negative-value]
static const int kElementsKindMask = (-1 << kElementsKindShift) &
                                        ~~ ^
../src/objects.h:7386:36: error: shifting a negative signed value is undefined [-Werror,-Wshift-negative-value](~kMaxCachedArrayIndexLength << kArrayIndexHashLengthShift) |
       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^
2 errors generated.
make[1]: *** [/Users/paras/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.13/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/v8_base/src/accessors.o] Error 1
make: *** [x64.release] Error 2
/Users/paras/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.13/ext/libv8/location.rb:36:in `block in verify_installation!': libv8 did not install properly, expected binary v8 archive '/Users/paras/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.13/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/tools/gyp/libv8_base.a'to exist, but it was not found (Libv8::Location::Vendor::ArchiveNotFound)
from /Users/paras/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.13/ext/libv8/location.rb:35:in `each'
from /Users/paras/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.13/ext/libv8/location.rb:35:in `verify_installation!'
from /Users/paras/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.13/ext/libv8/location.rb:26:in `install!'
from extconf.rb:7:in `<main>'
GYP_GENERATORS=make \
build/gyp/gyp --generator-output="out" build/all.gyp \-Ibuild/standalone.gypi --depth=. \-Dv8_target_arch=x64 \-S.x64  -Dv8_enable_backtrace=1 -Dv8_can_use_vfp2_instructions=true -Darm_fpu=vfpv2 -Dv8_can_use_vfp3_instructions=true -Darm_fpu=vfpv3 -Dwerror=''CXX(target) /Users/paras/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.13/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/allocation.o
  CXX(target) /Users/paras/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.13/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/atomicops_internals_x86_gcc.o
  CXX(target) /Users/paras/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.13/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/bignum.o
  CXX(target) /Users/paras/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.13/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/bignum-dtoa.o
  CXX(target) /Users/paras/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.13/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/cached-powers.o
  CXX(target) /Users/paras/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.13/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/conversions.o
  CXX(target) /Users/paras/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.13/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/diy-fp.o
  CXX(target) /Users/paras/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.13/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/dtoa.o
  CXX(target) /Users/paras/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.13/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/fast-dtoa.o
  CXX(target) /Users/paras/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.13/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/fixed-dtoa.o
  CXX(target) /Users/paras/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.13/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/once.o
  CXX(target) /Users/paras/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.13/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/preparse-data.o
  CXX(target) /Users/paras/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.13/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/preparser.o
  CXX(target) /Users/paras/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.13/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/preparser-api.o
  CXX(target) /Users/paras/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.13/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/scanner.o
  CXX(target) /Users/paras/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.13/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/strtod.o
  CXX(target) /Users/paras/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.13/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/token.o
  CXX(target) /Users/paras/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.13/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/unicode.o
  CXX(target) /Users/paras/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.13/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/utils.o
  LIBTOOL-STATIC /Users/paras/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.13/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/libpreparser_lib.a
  CXX(target) /Users/paras/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.13/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/preparser/preparser/preparser-process.o
  LINK(target) /Users/paras/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.13/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/preparser
  CXX(target) /Users/paras/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.13/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/v8_base/src/accessors.o
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two possible issues:

Looks like you're missing the native extensions for `libv8`:

1. First, make sure your OSX dev tools are installed and up to date
2. Reinstall `v8` via homebrew, then reinstall `libv8` and `therubyracer`

   brew tap homebrew/versions
   brew uninstall v8
   brew install v8-315
   gem uninstall -a libv8
   gem uninstall -a therubyracer
   gem install libv8 -v '3.16.14.13' -- --with-system-v8
   gem install therubyracer -v '0.12.1' -- --with-v8-dir=$(brew --prefix v8-315)

Source: https://github.com/cowboyd/libv8/issues/205. (Had a similar issue and the above worked for me.)